# Replacing a key value in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks something like this

```
        my_dictionary={
                ("today is", "tomorrow"): 1.34,
                ("tomorrow", "today is"):2.6}
                 etc
```

I am trying to make it so that if the user wants to change the value of any of these values they can.

earlier on in the program:

```
  value= my_dictionary[item_1, item_2}
```

I tried using this

```
def new():
   global choice
   global change
   choice=input("Would you like to change a value?")
   if choice=="yes":
      change=input("Which terms?")
      if change in my_dictionary:
         value=float(input("Enter value: "))
         my_dictionary[change]=value
      else:
         print("Term doesn't exist.")
```

But this doesn't work. It takes me straight to 'Term doesn't exist'
I've never coded anything that replaced, appended, deleted anything from a dictionary.
If someone has any idea I would be very appreciative.
Thank you.

So it goes:
Would you like to change a value? yes
Which terms?today is, tomorrow
Term doesn't exist.

this happens with and without the comma
also even if I type just one item in still doesn't work-it just moves on to the next part of the program.
I need to change the value of two terms specifically so they must be typed in the correct order.

Comment: The if and else do not seem to be indented correctly. Please correct the indentation? Also, please let us know the input on which the code is erroring

Comment: I just edited. Hope it's more clear, I'm not very familiar with dictionaries.

Comment: What do you expect the user to enter when you ask him for `change=input("Which terms?")`?

Comment: today is, tomorrow (the first two items)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is basically always structured in this way:

```
my_dict = {
           key: value,
           key: value,
           key: value... #etc, etc
          }
```

...where each 'key' is a *different* variable. The 'values' needn't be different, though typically they are.

You are able to add or modify a dictionary key-value pair by simply typing:

```
my_dict[key] = value
```

...where 'key' is the 'first' variable and 'value' is the second.

If you're going to use tuples for keys, however, searching for a key will require an exact match. If you have a dictionary with a structure like this:

```
my_dict = {
           ('one', 'key'):value,
           ('two', 'key'):other_value,
            ....etc.....
          }
```

...and you try to say `if 'one' in my_dict`, it will return `False` because you didn't use the exact item that's being used as the key. You would use a syntax like `if ('one', 'key') in my_dict` to match that *exact* key.

Comment: Thank you.Devoted answer. I'm getting there. It changes the value but only temporarily, it doesn't store it for some reason so when I start up the program again the dict will not contain the new value.

Comment: Ah, indeed - if you want the changes to persist, you'll need to alter your approach to include a library like `pickle` to save the object as-is and load it in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` you get from `input` is a string, while the keys for your dictionary are tuples.

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert a string to a tuple;

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 31 2014, 00:17:41) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("('a', 'b')")
('a', 'b')
```

Or you can split up the string:

```
>>> tuple('a, b'.split(','))
('a', ' b')
```

Comment: To be honest, sir, I saw an example of this in a book. I tried to make it so that it works with my code too. The only thing I changed was the variable names and the dictionary. The code in the book works and technically this one should too. You are superior to me about python but am I wrong in assuming that what you just said would mean the program would be more complicated? How would I make it so that the input can match what is in the dictionary? Any advice?

Comment: The OPs input is "today is, tomorrow" as noted in the comments. Not "('today is', 'tomorrow')" for ast.literal_eval to work?

Comment: @shaktimaan Edited the answer to cover that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the user to enter "today is, tomorrow" as you noted in the comments, then your code is not equipped to handle it.

The keys in your dictionary are tuples, where as the user input is always a string. You have to transform the user input as a tuple.

You do it like this:

```
change=input("Which terms?")
change_list = change.split(',')
change_list = [a.strip() for a in change_list]
change_tuple = tuple(change_list)
```

Now check if `change_tuple` is in the dictionary with:

```
if change_tuple in my_dictionary:
```

Rest of the code seems ok.

Comment: See, I did my program so that it loops. The user is asked if they want to run the program again. If they say yes and use they use the value that they change previously. However. If I shut down the program and ask to use the same two items, they don't use the changed value. They use the original value. I thought that the code would change the original value with the one that the user entered, or is that not how it works? By the way, thank you. I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Your key in this dictionary is a tuple. So if you want to change the value in the dictionary, you need to enter a tuple.

```
choice=raw_input("Would you like to change a value?")
if choice=="yes":
    change=input("Which terms?")

    if change in my_dictionary:
        value=float(input("Enter value: "))
        my_dictionary[change]=value
    else:
        print("Term doesn't exist.")
```

The result of running this code and entering correct key values:

```
Would you like to change a value?yes
Which terms?("today is", "tomorrow")
Enter value: 1.35
```